# How to extract all elements from array of structs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with different columns and where one of the column is an array of structs:

```
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------+
|id        |title    |                                values|
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------+
|        1 | aaa     |      [{name1, id1}, {name2, id2},...]|
|        2 | bbb     |  [{name11, id11}, {name22, id22},...]|
```

my df schema for this column looks like this:

```
|-- values: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

I want to extract each value from this array column like this:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
|id        |title    |name   |   _id|
+----------+---------+--------------+
|        1 | aaa     | name1 |  id1 |
|        1 | aaa     | name2 |  id2 |
|        2 | bbb     | name11| id11 |
|        2 | bbb     | name22| id22 |
```

I figured out how to extract the single item of the array:

```
df = df.withColumn("name", df["values"].getItem(0).name)\
.withColumn("_id", df["id"].getItem(0).id)\
```

but I don't know the way how to apply it for the whole length of array. I probably should do something like:

```
for index in range(len(df.values)):
    df = df.withColumn("name", df["values"].getItem(index).name)\
    .withColumn("_id", df["id"].getItem(index).id)\
```

could you please help me to solve it ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just `explode` and select

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

df.withColumn("values", explode("values")).select(
  "*", col("values")["name"].alias("name"), col("values")["id"].alias("id")
)
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question : What if I dont know the exactly element name in the struct, how can I extract all elements from it ? In this case, we have already known that two elements in struct are `name` and `id` specifically.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding the solution a bit further. Instead of individually extracting each struct elements, you can use this approach to select all elements in the struct fields, by using col("col_name.*").

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

df.withColumn("values", explode("values")).select(
"*",col("values.*")
)
```